# windows explorer cannot open a jpg or png image

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

windows version - `20H2`
windows (file) explorer
img thumbnails are all there
but clicking on a `.jpg` or `.png` file I'm getting this error:
`File system error (-2147416359)`
viewing a `.webp` image - no problem
pls help

Comment: have you googled this error and tried the various things that are suggested? What happened when you did?

Comment: @AlexM - I found only solutions for older win versions - 2018 and similar

Comment: You can use *SFC /ScanNow* and then  *DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth* to repair Windows. Or you could install another image tool, such as IrfanView, and set it to display JPEG and PNG files.